# Oracle Apex Add validation for Grid column

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an Interactive Grid:

```
select emp_id, dept_id, emp_name,dept_name from employees;
```

For DEPT_ID column, the dept_id when entered should match from the list of dept ids in Departments table, i.e. select dept_id,dept_name from departments;

1. How can i add the validation so that when dept_id is entered it validates whether it is present in departments table or not?
2. Dept_name should populate on basis of dept_id selected. How can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong approach, from my point of view.

Interactive Grid should be

```
select emp_id, dept_id, emp_name from employees;
```

(i.e. without department name).

DEPT_ID column should be a **select list** item with list of values that looks like this:

```
select dept_name as display_value,
       dept_id   as return_value
from departments
order by dept_name;
```

Now you fixed two things:

- you can't insert invalid department because list of values prevents you from doing it
- data model will be normalized

  - you shouldn't store department name along with its ID into the employees table;
  - there should be referential integrity constraint between these two tables